# A website to select just hotels on the Strip in Las Vegas?

Tags: online-resources, hotels, las-vegas

Is there an online booking site (eg booking.com, airbnb.com) that lets you select **JUST** the hotels on The Strip in Las Vegas?

Some of the problem I'm having stems from the fact that The Strip is *technically* not in Las Vegas City itself...

I remember going there 10.5 years ago (wow) and using [LasVegas.com](http://www.lasvegas.com), but it appears to have expanded out to *everything* Vegas-oriented.

By 'The Strip' I mean everything between The Stratosphere and the other end (Mandalay Bay) - or as [Wiki says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_Strip):

> The Las Vegas Strip is an approximately 4.2-mile (6.8 km) stretch of
>   Las Vegas Boulevard South...The traditional definition considers the
>   Strip's northern terminus as the now-defunct Sahara Casino, though
>   travel guides typically extend it to include the Stratosphere, 0.4
>   miles (0.64 km) to the north. At one time, the southern end of the
>   Strip was Tropicana Avenue, but continuing construction has extended
>   this boundary to Russell Road. Mandalay Bay is located just north of
>   Russell Road and is the southernmost resort considered to be on the
>   Strip.

Comment: Not sure whether it is practically helpful, but [Paul Carr's The Strip Diary series](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/paul-carr/the-strip-diary-epilogue-_b_858919.html) of a living in hotel a day for a month on The Strip may give you some helpful pointers. Unfortunately, the tag link is broken so you may need to [use a site search instead](http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=A0oG7hn_FBFQnlEAQI5XNyoA?p=site%3Ahuffingtonpost.com%20%22the%20strip%20diary%22&fr2=sb-top&fr=sfp&rd=pref) to find all articles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Booking.com has "District" as one of the filter criteria on the left hand side of your search result. When searching for hotels in Vegas, "Las Vegas Strip" shows up as a district. Selecting that seems to* reduce the results to exactly what you are looking for.

* At a glance all the hotels seem to be on the strip, but Booking.com's definition of the Strip may not exactly match the Wiki one.

Comment: It looks pretty accurate to me +1

Answer (score 2):

Although it not is an aggregator, you could use google maps for this. Locate your area first, and once you have done that type "Hotel" as search term. The following picture shows.

[image: google maps]

Source: [Google maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Hotel&hl=nl&sll=36.116245,-115.169334&sspn=0.100676,0.198097&hq=Hotel&t=m&z=13)
Each dot is suppose to be a hotel.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the web sites for each of the major hotel chains (mlife.com, totalrewards.com, venetian.com, wynn.com) and you have almost every Strip property worth staying at, right there. Also cosmopolitanlv.com, stratosphere.com .

Priceline also IIRC has zones that cover only Strip hotels.